# Android automatically delete everything before last 2 minutes of video stream

Tags: android, camera

I want to make an android app, that records a video stream and when the user does **not** push a button, everything before the last 120 seconds of the video stream gets deleted. This should run for hours so only ~50mb are in use all the time. Has anyone an idea how to record a video like a never-ending flow of data that allows me to access certain points and delete everything before those points?

I know this question is pretty general but I find it very hard to access android camera close to the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably run into file size limitations if nothing else.

A better approach would be to just keep recording 30-second videos, and delete any that are more than two minutes old until the user presses the "record" button, at which time you start keeping them.

Then splice them together into one long video afterwards.

By the way, this will kill your battery. I assume you're equipped to deal with that.